# Collecting data on device and send it once a day to IoT Central but keeping timestamp from collected data

Tags: azure-iot-central

would like to ask a question if someone of you have an idea or could point me into the right direction.
My situation is as the following. The device I use collects data every hour and stores it internally with timestamp (Unix timestamp). The device can only send its data once a day to IoT Central, but when the data arrived the data will be stored with the actual time, but not with the original timestamp.
How can I prevent IoT Central from using its own timestamp and use the one device provides?

Would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Thanks
Init5

Comment: Have you considered adding another telemetry (or property) to your device template for the local timestamp so the device can report and store it this way?

Comment: @Init5 still blocked or the hint from Stefan helped you move forward? See also [System Properties of D2C IoT Hub messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct#system-properties-of-d2c-iot-hub-messages) the same applies for IoT Central.

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT: yes, that’s what I am doing right now. But this does not solves the problem. As an example: my device has collected two data sets. Each contains a timestamp and a value. The first data set has the timestamp from 1 pm and the other one from 2 pm. At 3 pm my device connects to IoT Central and sends these two data sets. Both will have nearly the same timestamp (actually the time, when IoT Central Stores them) but I am not able to bring the value from my data set with the timestamps from 1pm / 2pm in line with the values.

Comment: @asergaz I still trying but it might also be a misunderstanding from my side. IoT in Microsoft context means (as I understood) every event has to be send when it occurs. What I try to do is to send „historical“ data - even if they are just a few hours old. I can do this for example with SAP IoT Services (that’s SAP counterpart of Azure IoT Hub) if I overwrite or set the „_timestamp“. But I have no glue how to do this here?

Comment: @Init5 by default IoT Central is a SaaS offer that reduces the burden and cost of developing, managing, and maintaining your IoT app. When you need to customize it, so that for instance analyze historical data you can export data and do it with [Time Series Insights](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/) - still, I believe you can customize your dashboards and select custom properties to show on your dashboard -  [Configure the application dashboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-add-tiles-to-your-dashboard) Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer based on comments above:

IoT Central is a SaaS offer that reduces the burden and cost of developing, managing, and maintaining your IoT app. When you need to customize it, so that for instance analyze historical data you can export data and do it with [Time Series Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/) - You can customize your dashboards and select custom properties to show on your dashboard - [Configure the application dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-add-tiles-to-your-dashboard)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. You pointed me in the right direction. At the end I set up the export to the event hub, modified the data with a azure function app and pushed it to the TSI. worked fine.